# $ \iint_{D} |f(x,y)|\,dx\,dy$ is not finite and $ \iint_{D} \sqrt{|f(x,y)|}\,dx\,dy$ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $$f:D=[-1,1]\times [-1,1]\to \mathbb{R},~ (x,y)\mapsto \begin{cases}\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0, & (x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases}. $$

I checked that this function is not continuous at $(0,0)$ and its partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ does not exist. Now I need to prove the following things:

1. $\displaystyle \iint_D|f(x,y)|~dxdy$ is not finite and
2. $\displaystyle \iint_D\sqrt{|f(x,y)|}~dxdy$ is finite.

I can write $$f(x,y) = \dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right). $$ But, how do I solve this, as it might blows up in the domain?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ is not integrable on $(0,1)^2$ (it is a celebrated example of the [failure of Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini%27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions)), but

$$ \iint_{(0,1)^2}|g(x,y)|\,dx\,dy = 2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy\,dx=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{2x}=+\infty$$
and

$$\iint_{(0,1)^2}\sqrt{|g(x,y)|}\,dx\,dy = 2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}}\,dy\,dx=\pi(\sqrt{2}-1).$$

About the last integral:
$$\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\frac{dy}{x^2+y^2}\stackrel{y\mapsto xz}{=}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}\,dz\stackrel{z\mapsto\cos\theta}{=}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos^2\theta}{1+\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta $$
equals, via $\theta\mapsto\arctan(u)$,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^2}{(1+t^2)(2+t^2)}\,dt=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2}{2+t^2}-\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)\,dt=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi}{2}. $$

Comment: Could you please tell me how did you do the last integral $\displaystyle\int_0^x{\sqrt{\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}}\,dy}$?

Comment: Please give little details for the second integral.

Comment: @XYZABC: done .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Due to the symmetry in the problem, we can say that

$$\iint_D g(x,y)\:dA = 8 \int_0^1 \int_0^x g(x,y) \:dy\:dx$$

Can you compute the integrals from here?

Comment: Alternatively you could try to justify a p-test argument in polar coordinates for both, but the for the first one it is simpler to compute the integral in this way.

Comment: I guess the constant that pops out from the integral should be $4$. Yes this way I proved that $$I= \int_0^1\dfrac{1}{2x}dx \text{ and other integral is } \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x}}dx $$ and hence proved.

Comment: @XYZABC The constant is $8$, not $4$

Comment: I see, there are $4$ parts of the square and you are doing the integral in half of the first part which in the first quadrant. That's why you are getting $8$. Am I right?

Comment: @XYZABC that is correct. We use the even symmetry in both $x$ and $y$ to reduce the integral to a single quadrant, then use the $g(x,y) = g(y,x)$ exchange symmetry to reduce the integral to just half the quadrant.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to evaluate the second integral?